# Calculate Percentage of results equaling a value within a date range

Tags: excel, filter, countif

I'm attempting to write a formula that will show a completion % from multiple columns within a date range on a sheet. I have it working if I put the exact cell range in the formula like this: =COUNTIF(Jason!B2:K31,"COMPLETE")/COUNTA(Jason!B2:K31) Specifically I'm looking for the number of tasks marked complete in all cells over a month and showing a %.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVP9h.jpg)

This will be a running document updated daily so I want to be able to use a formula that will filter the results by month.
[Daily Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQfWj.jpg)

I have tried using =COUNTIF(FILTER(Jason!B2:K31,(Jason!A2:A31>=Performance!B3)*(Jason!A2:A31<Performance!B4),"None"),"COMPLETE") but apparently you can't use FILTER that way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use Two SUMPRODUCTS

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Jason!B2:K31="COMPLETE")*(Jason!A2:A31>=Performance!B3)*(Jason!A2:A31<Performance!B4))/SUMPRODUCT((Jason!B2:K31<>"")*(Jason!A2:A31>=Performance!B3)*(Jason!A2:A31<Performance!B4))
```

We can use LET to get rid of some of the duplicates:

```
=LET(r,Jason!B2:K31,
     ld,Performance!B3,
     hd,Performance!B4,
     d,Jason!A2:A31,
     arr,(d>=ld)*(d<hd),
     SUMPRODUCT((r="COMPLETE")*arr)/SUMPRODUCT((r<>"")*arr)
```